# ETH transaction not received. Can someone help?

Tags: ledger-nano-s

I made a transaction to my Ledger Nano S ETH wallet from Wirex that has not been credited. Instead of a Normal Transaction it's showing as an Internal Transaction (0.333 ETH) which means that I have no ac:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x3BbDa23d01EF536Ceee82520dFcC6CF96412De7e#internaltx

Wirex have told me 'contact the receiving party so they process the payment' but I do not understand what does that mean? Who is the receiving party and how is the payment processed?

Can someone assist?

Comment: What wallet are you using? The balances are credited immediately after the transaction is mined, for "internal" transactions or regular transactions. The wallet should show the same balance than Etherscan.

Comment: Wirex are useless. If the receiving party will not move the ETH then you have lost it due to Wireex's unorthodox practises.